# The rectilinear crossing number vs crossing number

Tags: graph-theory

The rectilinear crossing number of a graph $G$ denoted by $\overline{cr}(G)$ on $n$ vertices is the minimum number of crossings between edges of $G$ among all possible drawing of $G$ such that all its edges are straight. As opposed to the crossing number $cr(G)$, which is the minimal number of crossings of edges of $G$ in all possible drawing of $G$.

For a planar graphs $G$, $cr(G)=\overline{cr}(G)$. Is there an example in which the two are not the same? Is there an example in which $\overline{cr}(G)>> cr(G)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and yes.

The paper [Bounds for Rectilinear Crossing Number](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/jgt.3190170308) by Bienstock and Dean gives the following construction for a graph with crossing number $4$ but arbitrarily large rectilinear crossing number.

Start with the following graph:

[image]

It has blue edges and red edges. In the rectilinear picture drawn, some red edges and blue edges intersect. It's possible to draw some of the red edges as arcs to get a different picture, in which the red edges avoid crossing any blue edges, and have only 4 crossings. But it's not possible to avoid all red-blue crossings with straight edges.

Now extend this graph by replacing every blue edge $xy$ with $m$ edge-disjoint paths of length $2$ starting at $x$ and ending at $y$. This has the effect of making blue edges count $m$ times as much. So:

- the picture with $4$ red crossings (which cannot be realized with straight edges) still has crossing number $4$,
- but the straight-line drawing above no longer has crossing number $12$ but $4m+8$,
- and in general, there is no straight-line drawing that gets the crossing number below $m$, because a blue edge has to cross a red edge.

Comment: Like, do you just register to view the paper? I'll try lol

Comment: I have access through my university. I'm not sure how easy it is to find the paper otherwise. The paper says the same things I do, but carefully proves things about the non-existence of certain embeddings that I just say without justification.